# oAuth2 JWT token validation process

Tags: validation, oauth-2.0, jwt

I am looking for documentation on Google oAuth2 JWT token verification process. In my use-case, I am going to send the JWT token from my client and the server code is responsible for validating the JWT token. My backend will be responsible for validating the oAuth2 JWT token as per spec, so I need a formal process on what needs to be done in-order to validate the JWT token instead of just using the libraries.

I am using Spring library to do that, but I am looking for information like how to get the certificates and use them if we are making call to Google API for validation.

If I am client, then all I need is just a client_id and ApiKey. But here I also see that we do need to provide certificates. Please let me know If I am wrong.

Comment: I am mostly interested to know how to import the private certificate in the keystore file locally.

Answer (score 2):

For validating a signed JWT, you should look at its header part and the properties `alg` (algorithm used for making a signature) and `kid` (signature encryption key ID). Load the Google OAuth 2 discovery JSON document
https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration and read its `jwks_uri` property (URL with encryption keys). Read the keys from that URL (it's a JSON document) and find a key with `use="sig"` (used for signing) and matching `alg` and `kid` values. Then you can decrypt the JWT signature to get the JWT hash value and compare it with your calculated hash value.

So you don't need to import a key to your keystore. You can cache the keys, but when you get a `kid` value not contained in the cache, you need to read the JWKS document again. There is also a possibility of Google removing some keys over time.

Comment: Thank you Jan. This was helpful.  I also found this blog very informative https://ncona.com/2015/02/consuming-a-google-id-token-from-a-server/